# Create a Macro to convert UPC E Barcode to UPC A

Tags: excel, vba

My problem is that after the first loop oldupc is still referenced to A1 not off setting to A2, I created msgboxes to track progress in the loop. Do I need to Offset every Cell?

Sub ConvertUPCE()

```
Dim OldUPC As String
Dim NewUPC As String
Dim K As Double, i As Double
Dim L As Integer

OldUPC = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value
NewUPC = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
K = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
L = ActiveCell.Value
    MsgBox (K)
'MsgBox OldUPC
'MsgBox NewUPC
'MsgBox L

Range("c1").Select

 For i = 1 To 11

 If (L >= 0 And L <= 3) Then
      ActiveCell.Value2 = "'" & Mid(OldUPC, 1, 1) & Mid(OldUPC, 2, 2) & Mid(OldUPC, 7, 1) & "0000" & Mid(OldUPC, 4, 3)
      ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select


       ElseIf (L = 4) Then
         ActiveCell.Value2 = "'" & Mid(OldUPC, 1, 1) & Mid(OldUPC, 2, 3) & "00000" & Mid(OldUPC, 5, 2)

       ElseIf (L = 5) Then
         ActiveCell.Value2 = "'" & Mid(OldUPC, 1, 1) & Mid(OldUPC, 2, 4) & "00000" & Mid(OldUPC, 6, 1)
         ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

       ElseIf (L >= 6 And L <= 9) Then
         ActiveCell.Value2 = "'" & Mid(OldUPC, 1, 1) & Mid(OldUPC, 2, 5) & "0000" & Mid(OldUPC, 7, 1)
         ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select


         Else: ActiveCell.Value = "Not Vailid Check Digit"

      End If

      'MsgBox OldUPC
      MsgBox OldUPC

 Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend against using `ActiveCell` and instead use the iteration integer as a cell row.

Like so: `Cells(i, 3).value2 = ...`, where i is the row number and 3 is the column number (since you are in column C).

Then you can offset with `Cells(i,3).Offset(1,0).select`.

This will also make the code run faster since you are not selecting each cell before you manipulate the data.

Tip: If you want to iterate through rows and columns, you can do the following and not worry about what is selected and what is next:

```
For RowNum = 1 to 11
    For ColNum = 1 to 11
        Cells(RowNum, ColNum).value = ""
    Next ColNum
Next RowNum
```

-So this will run through 11 columns for each row for 11 rows!